# Cycling images with javascript

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the second (hawk) image appear when the button is clicked? It goes straight to the else statement showing the ant image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function changeImg() {
                if (document.getElementById("cycle").src == "fox.jpg") {
                    document.getElementById("cycle").src = "hawk.jpg";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("cycle").src = "ant.jpg";
                }
            }
        </script>

        <button onclick = "changeImg()">change image</button>
        <img id ="cycle" src ="fox.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: save yourself typing and cache your element `var cycle = document.getElementById("cycle");` then you can just do `cycle.src` instead of `document.getElementById` everytime.

Comment: Here is your lesson in debugging javascript: use `console.log`. I made you a fiddle with your code, but added a log statement for the `.src`. https://jsfiddle.net/z9dojguu/ open the console. Notice anything with the src that is logged versus what you are checking for?

Comment: The if goes to `else` because it doesn't know what image is there. So the `if` is doing nothing actually.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your script tags at the end of the body to make sure that your dom is rendered before accessing any elements. (like in my example)
The problem with your code is, that you need to add a new if for every new image you add. As you noticed yourself, it becomes hard to understand and debug.
For something like cycling, use an array and modulo operation on the index of that array.

With this solution, you can add as many images to the images array as you like, without touching the code/logic;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="changeImg()">change image</button>
  <img id="cycle" />

  <script>
    var imageElement = document.getElementById("cycle");
    var images = ["fox.jpg", "hawk.jpg", "ant.jpg"]; // add as many images as you want
    var counter = 0;
    imageElement.src = images[counter] // set the initial image

    function changeImg() {
      counter = (counter + 1) % images.length;     
      imageElement.src = images[counter];
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. But can you explain how the function loops back to the first image after the last image?

Comment: He's using the remainder operator. Each time the changeImg function is run, it increments by 1. It starts at 0, then goes to 1, then 2, then three...oops, the array only has three items. So, divide the counter by the length of the array (3) and take the remainder and use THAT for the index. When the counter is 3, it divides by 3, the remainder is 0, and sets the counter back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("cycle").src` always has full url of image (example:https://example.loc/example/fox.jpg) and this is not similar  from fox.jpg. 
You need try another solution.Try use
 `cycle.getAttribute('src')`

Example code:

```
function changeImg() {
          let cycle = document.getElementById("cycle");
               console.log(cycle.src,cycle.getAttribute('src')); // show real value and taribute      
            if (cycle.getAttribute('src') == "fox.jpg") {
                cycle.src = "hawk.jpg";
            } else {cycle.src = "ant.jpg";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getAttribute('src')` if you want to access the actual contents of the attribute. Otherwise you get the resolved URL.

```
var cycle = document.getElementById("cycle");
if (cycle.getAttribute('src') == "fox.jpg") {
    cycle.src = "hawk.jpg";
} else {
    cycle.src = "ant.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I mistakenly clicked decrease, please edit youre poste, and I increase it.